# Convertir Subconsulta Mysql a Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Quiero crear esta subconsulta en Laravel eloquent,

```
SELECT * FROM `obras` 
WHERE id_usuario = (select id from `artistas` WHERE status = 'enabled')
```

Ayuda :(

*La consulta mysql de ejemplo funciona a la perfección

Tengo esta consulta, funciona como quiero, pero en el id me manda el id del artista y necesito el id de la Obra

```
$ar = Artista::select('id','name')
               ->where('status','=','enabled');

$obras = Obras::joinSub($ar, 'obras_artista', function ($join) {
                $join->on('id_usuario', '=', 'obras_artista.id');
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que deseas se acerca mas a hacer un Join a esas 2 tablas para obtener el resultado, podrías intentar con algo así:

```
Artistas::Join('obras', function ($join) {
            $join->on('obras.id_usuario', '=', 'artistas.id');
        })
        ->select('artistas.id as id_artista', 'obras.*')
        ->get();
```

Siempre y cuando el query sea como el primero:

```
SELECT * FROM `obras` 
WHERE id_usuario = (select id from `artistas` WHERE status = 'enabled')
```

porque según lo que agregas, tal vez tengas mas de dos tablas, si adicionas las tablas que tienes tal vez se puede tener una aproximación mas cercana.

Comment: Tienes mucha razon, no lo habia contemplado de tal manera, crack

Comment: Consejos a ambos: Iván trata a futuras preguntas de dar toda la información necesaria desde el inicio para que sea fácil identificar tu problema el cual era muy simple de tratar , Felipe me causa intriga por qué un left join y no un simple join, yendo un poco más allá esto se resuelve muy simple y más al estilo de Laravel con Eloquent y sus relaciones

Comment: @BetaM que tal, en realidad debe ser un simple Join, reutilice un código que tenia, y no me fije de esa parte, ya lo edite.

Answer (score 0):

**EDICIÓN**

La primer respuesta que te ofrecí fue asumiendo que tu subconsulta retornada solo una fila, *claramente con lo expuesto en los comentarios no es así.*

Es raro que esa consulta te esté funcionando, por que de hecho esto:

```
WHERE id_usuario = (select id from `artistas` WHERE status = 'enabled')
```

Si retorna mas de una fila te debería generar este error ya que no existe modo óptimo y real de que la **igualdad** que buscas ocurra:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row in select statement

Lo ideal es que si usas esa subconsulta, entonces asegures que solo retornará una fila, en caso contrario tienes opciones como:

- `where in`
- joins
- las relaciones de Eloquent

Entonces si tomamos la última opción tu consulta debería ser algo como:

```
Artista::select('id')->has('obras')->with('obras')->whereStatus('enabled')->get();
```

Comment: Me funciona, pero solo para un usuario, cuando son mas de 2 usuarios con status enabled, no funciona

Comment: ¿Te regresa algún error?, de ser así cual es?

Comment: @Iván prueba quitando `first()` y agregando `get()`

Comment: si, probe eso, pero no me retorna nada,

Comment: A ver entonces para entender la consulta devuelve o no valores?

Comment: La consulta cuando pongo get() si retorna cuando hay un solo usuario, pero si hay mas de 2 usuarios con status "enabled" no retorna nada.

y en la consulta que yo tengo si retorna todos los usuarios que neceito, pero en vez de retornar el id de la obra, retorna el id del artista, solo necesito que regrese el id de la obra y listo

Comment: Es que ya con lo que comentas ni siquiera requieres de una subconsulta, por qué si requieres el ID de la obra y está tabla está relacionada a su vez con artistas entonces ocupamos un join y al final un where para filtrar por enabled, dime por ahí va idea?

Comment: Por qué de otra manera si la subconsulta retorna más de un valor dará error @Iván?